# Changing Windows 7 default user on bootup

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, shrew

Since I installed ShrewSoft VPN it defaults to the user when I boot up instead of my local user.  I'm not a fan of this since it's only rarely used and I would like for my admin account to be the default user.  Is there a setting or registry setting I can modify to put my local admin account back as the default user when my computer boots up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is ultimately controlled by registry but you dont need to go this far, there's a nice handy tick box you can change (and then provide default logon credentials)

Press windows & R for run box

type "netplwiz" or "control userpasswords2" - either will work fine

Untick "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer."

You will then be prompted to enter default login details, just OK this box unless you have a password in which case type this in, then apply and restart, PC will Auto-login.

Comment: If you've already done this, but have added a different user and want it to be the default, just re-tick, logoff, logon as the user you want defaulted, and repeat the above process. That will set the default user to a different user.

Comment: Please note that this method doesn't work for Windows 7 computers in a domain environment.  For that, see [@Craig Silver's answer](http://superuser.com/a/1125275/430831).

Answer (score 5):

I found that it was this:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI

LastLoggedOnSAMUser = Computername\username (or domainname\username for a domain account)

LastLoggedOnUser = .\username (or domainname\username for a domain account)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, went to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
and changed
DefaultDomainName and DefaultUserName values to the desired string data.
Additionally for auto-login it needs to be set (create it if it does not exist) the DefaultPassword value with the user password as string and also the string value AutoAdminLogon should be set to 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Easier method:

Type **`cmd`** (in search), and right click **`RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR`** and execute these commands (just change `User` with your actual username, and `WORKGROUP` with your actual [domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDgyt.png) name):

`reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /t REG_SZ /v DefaultDomainName /d` **`WORKGROUP`** `/f       &&       reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /t REG_SZ /v DefaultUserName /d` **`User`** `/f`

---

p.s.
`/t`  means type

`/v` means key

`/d` means value

`/f` means overwrite

Answer (score 0):

For CMD in Windows 7, run this 3 lines:

Modify domain to yout domain, and username to your username.

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /t REG_SZ /v LastLoggedOnProvider /d "" /f 
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /t REG_SZ /v LastLoggedOnUser /d "domain\username" /f 
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /t REG_SZ /v LastLoggedOnSAMUser /d "domain\username" /f
```