# Programs do not start until I log in via RDC on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I have a windows server that I use to run Plex and a few other home server type programs. Whenever the server boots up (after an update or power outage), I need to connect to it with RDC at least once before any of the services start up. How can I configure the machine to "log in" and start running programs without needing to actually log in or connect?

Comment: The same way it’s been done for 15+ years. Assign a default user. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1299362/how-to-stop-windows-from-loading-the-default-account-at-startup) is a well written answer how to disable it, instead of requiring a password, uncheck the checkbox requiring a password. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/368978/changing-windows-7-default-user-on-bootup) is a good duplicate

Comment: Alternatively you have Plex start as a service rather than as a user run program: https://www.plexopedia.com/plex-media-server/windows/running-plex-media-server-service/